# Polymer 2.0 Data Binding - from html property to Polymer class

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I want to have the same feature as Polymer paper-elements drop-down menu have with disabled.

The drop-down menu code:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Disabled dinosaurs" disabled>
 <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
    <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
    <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
    <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

In first row there is: `<paper-dropdown-menu label="Disabled dinosaurs" disabled>`

The question is how to pass to Polymer class that this.disabled = true if disabled parameter is in `<my-element tag>`?

So when i have `<my-element disabled> this.disabled=true` and if `<my element nothing there>` `this.disabled=false`?

Comment: can you update the code with <my-element>? Regular data-binding should work but implementation depends on where is <my-element>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should just work using polymer properties with a boolean type and reflectToAttribute.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0-rc.7/webcomponentsjs+v1.0.0-rc.11/shadydom+webcomponents+:master/shadycss+webcomponents+:master/components/">

 <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

 <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

<my-el disabled>
 <h3>Disabled Element</h3>
</my-el>
 
<my-el>
 <h3>Enabled Element</h3>
</my-el>


<dom-module id="my-el">
 <template>
  <style>
   .disabledInfo { display: none; }
   :host([disabled]) .disabledInfo { display: block; }
   :host([disabled]) .enabledInfo { display: none; }
  </style>
  <slot></slot>
  <div class="disabledInfo">I am disabled</div>
  <div class="enabledInfo">I am enabled</div>
  <br /><br />
 </template>
 <script>
  class MyEl extends Polymer.Element {
   static get properties() {
    return {
     disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      value: false
     }
    };
   }
   static get is() { return 'my-el'; }
  }
  customElements.define(MyEl.is, MyEl);
 </script>
</dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

See it also on codepen
http://codepen.io/daKmoR/pen/pPKJxN?editors=1000

Comment: this is okay, but how to reflect this "disabled" to JS variable? I know in this example we can read is disable in <html> and use in CSS, but how to read value of disabled in JS?

Comment: oh, everything is working fine when JS variable is "someWord" and in html is "some-word", but when variable is single word, then it wont work - any idea how?

Comment: in this example you can easily do

inside the class (e.g.) connectedCallback you can just use `this.disabled` which will return true/false

"externally" cou could use
`document.getElementsByTagName('my-el')[0].disabled` which would return true
`document.getElementsByTagName('my-el')[1].disabled` which would return false

you could also do getAttribute('disabled') which would return "" (empty string) if it's set or null if not